# Кроссбраузерность в IE < 11

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[Есть сайт](http://tarthur.github.io/web_aventura/).
При клике на изображение, все ненужное уходит вниз и остаются только стрелки - это стандартное поведение, можно увидеть в современных браузерах(напр. в хроме). Но в IE ниже 11 версии, все эти зоны не кликабельны.
Почему IE ниже 11 версии, так некрасиво себя ведет?

P/S.
В скриптах можно не искать. Тут даже cursor pointer не отрабатывает, а значит проблема на уровне html/css

[GitHub сайта.](https://github.com/tarthur/web_aventura/tree/master/app)

Comment: Приведите часть кода, с помощью которого эта функция делается. Иначе вопрос требует вникать в то, как это всё реализовано в данном случае. А поскольку не везде работает, то скорее всего можно сделать иначе.

Comment: со скриптами я пока не разбирался, так как он на уровне css/html не работает(а именно ie не видит cursor: pointer).

Answer (score 1):

Проблема с некликабельностью в IE прозрачных областей ссылок.
Лечилась, формальным заданием им фона background: rgba(0,0,0,0)